# When uploading/streaming to S3 do you actually upload "twice?"

Tags: amazon-s3

I was wondering, since an upload stream passes through the server's buffer and than passed from the server to S3, am I actually uploading the file "twice".

First time I load (or stream) the file to the local server and than from the server to the cloud? Is there a way to skip the middle man and pass the files straight to S3?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var zlib = require('zlib');
    var multipart = require('connect-multiparty')

    module.exports = function (router) {
        router.get('/', function (req,res) {
        res.render('upload')

        })
        router.post('/',multipart(), function (req,res) {
            var body = fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.path).pipe(zlib.createGzip());
            var s3obj = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'bucketName', Key: 'aFileName.ext'}});
            s3obj.upload({Body: body}).
                on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); }).
                send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
        })

    }
```

When I render 'upload' on the get request, this is the client side code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" method="post">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Am I going through my own server or am I uploading directly from the client?

Comment: Sure. You can directly upload to S3 from the client side. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Amazon_S3) is the documentation and examples.

Comment: But, in the exemple you sent, the body is implicitly written out in the code. In a real-world situation I would probably have to use req.files.file which will first fetch the file to the server before sending it to AWS, am I wrong?

Comment: Probably I didn't get your question right. What do you mean by "the body is implicitly written out in the code"? You can first upload the file to the local server and then send it to AWS. Or you could directly send the file to AWS (from the web front end), as indicated in the examples, and send only the file name (s3 key) to your local server.

Comment: Ok, it was me that misunderstood! Thanks!!